# HQL, can I parameterize the FROM clause?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, hsqldb

I have this HQL query:

```
        Query q = em.createQuery (
        "DELETE FROM Annotation a WHERE a.id IN ( " +
        "  SELECT ja.id FROM :entityName an JOIN an.annotations ja)"
    );
```

and I'm being told: QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 1
Do I have any hope of making the entity name after FROM a parameter? I have a list of entities to send to this query and I'm afraid that string concatenation is too slow.

Comment: NO, as much as I know, it can't be. You should use `Criteria API` or build query string then pass to method.

Comment: Thanks sunisky. Criteria would be a partial solution, since it doesn't seem that one can issue an update operation with that API, but I could split this into select+delete. Building the string is what I'm doing, but HQL parsing makes things slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't substitute the Entity name the parameters work for entity properties not instead.

You could select the entities ids to be deleted with one query and then pass them to a second delete query, but for READ_COMMITED transaction isolation you might still end up with someone else inserting one child entity that would have matched your query. SERIALIZABLE will solve this issue.

Comment: the problem is I have a large number of subclasses of Annotatable (the one having the 'annotations' property) and it's ugly to list them in advance (I expect the same class to be extended in dependant packages). Basically, I'm realising the painful way that no relational stuff is good for these things.

Comment: Is there any way to use an inheritance model and map them to the same association?

Comment: No. This is the top class of a large tree, where there are several Annotatable that need their own mapping table. JOIN mapping isn't attractive either, due to performance reasons. I think the relational model is fundamentally limited for use cases like this.